# How to delete values (in my case: 'phones') from json file

Tags: python, json, with-statement, del

I'm new to json file syntax and I was wondering how to delete "phones" and its values from my json file so that end, start, alignedWord, and word are my only values in the words key.

## My Code:

```
with open('dest_file.json', 'w') as dest_file:
    with open('test1.json', 'r') as j:
        contents = json.loads(j.read())
        for value in contents['words']:
            del(value['case'])
            del(value['endOffset'])
            del(value['startOffset'])
        dest_file.write(json.dumps(contents,indent = 4))
```

## Example JSON object:

```
"words": [
        {
            "alignedWord": "the",
            "end": 6.31,
            "phones": [
                {
                    "duration": 0.09,
                    "phone": "dh_B"
                },
                {
                    "duration": 0.05,
                    "phone": "iy_E"
                }
            ],
            "start": 6.17,
            "word": "The"
        },
```

In addition to this, what exactly datatype is phones exactly and why was I not able to delete it via my current code?

Answer (score 0):

Inside a JSON elements, you can manipulate data either like an array / list, or as a dict. In this case, you can do `value.pop("phones")`.

e.g.

```
import json

data = '''
[
{
    "alignedWord": "the",
    "end": 6.31,
    "phones": [
        {
            "duration": 0.09,
            "phone": "dh_B"
        },
        {
            "duration": 0.05,
            "phone": "iy_E"
        }
    ],
    "start": 6.17,
    "word": "The"
}]'''

contents = json.loads(data)
for value in contents:
  value.pop('phones')

print(json.dumps(contents))
```

See it running: https://repl.it/repls/DarkgreyLightcoralInstitution

Comment: Running your code line I get the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsonIterator.py", line 35, in <module>
    value.pop("phones")
KeyError: 'phones'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If you want to save the edited json to a new file:

```
import json

with open('dest_file.json', 'w') as dest_file:
    with open('source_file.json', 'r') as source_file:
        for line in source_file:
            element = json.loads(line.strip())
            if 'phones' in element:
                del element['phones']
            dest_file.write(json.dumps(element))
```

If you want to re-write to the same json after editing:

```
import json

with open('dest_file.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for element in data:
    if 'phones' in element:
        del element['phones']

with open('dest_file.json', 'w') as data_file:
    data = json.dump(data, data_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

"phones" in above case will be a list of dictionaries. Also the "words" in itself is list of dictionaries itself. You need to access items in list first and then can jump on to dictionary pops as suggested above.

```py
words =[
        {
            "alignedWord": "the",
            "end": 6.31,
            "phones": [
                {
                    "duration": 0.09,
                    "phone": "dh_B"
                },
                {
                    "duration": 0.05,
                    "phone": "iy_E"
                }
            ],
            "start": 6.17,
            "word": "The"
        }
]
```

to display the single element:

```
words[0]['phones']
```

to remove:

```
words[0].pop('phones')
```

you can use above code to iterate and pop as suggested!